# Installing Ubuntu 17.04 (in dual boot with Windows 10): Bootloader failed to install

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, bootloader, 17.04

After deciding elementary OS is too temperamental for my laptop, I decided to replace it with Ubuntu 17.04. I have Windows 10 installed in a separate partition and have successfully dual booted Linux in the past. This time, however, towards the very end of the installation process, I get a warning telling me that the installer was unable to install the Grub2 bootloader.

I am using a USB installation media created using Rufus 2.15. Following the advice of answers to various similar questions, I have so far ensured that the installation media is created on a freshly FAT32-formatted USB stick, and have attempted installation both directly from the boot menu and from a Live session. I also ran the boot-info utility that generated a [Boot-Info log](https://paste2.org/dbDm08xa).

Comment: @DavidFoerster this isn't a duplicate, as I am not installing Ubuntu as the only OS, the error is different, _and_ that question's solution did not work when I tried it. How can I remove the duplication flag?

Comment: Done. Here's the link: https://paste2.org/dbDm08xa

Comment: try these directions.... seems maybe I missed some bindings  https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/293759

Comment: What happens when you perform the suggested repair of Boot-Repair like ravery recommends?

Comment: By following the directions I appear to have succesfully fixed the bootloader. Upon signing into Ubuntu however I have been given an error, telling me that a problem occurred while installing the package "shim-signed 1.28+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1. Is this an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have found on some systems, that the error isn't actually the install but grub update that fails. the file /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware errors breaking the creation of grubs config file.

edit it to read:

```
set -e

gettext_printf "Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration\n" >&2

cat << EOF

menuentry 'uefi-firmware' {

fwsetup

}

EOF
```

and the grub install should complete. the last line of the installer menu should be a command line, nano is the editor.
if not then complete install without the bootloader and make the corections via a live cd. then update grub for the installation.

Comment: Thank you for such a speedy response. For clarification, how do I make these corrections via the live USB session? Is it a simple case of editing that file you mentioned? If so, how do I then update grub as mentioned?

Comment: make a folder called target in the home folder. assuming your install partition is sda2, type: sudo mount /dev/sda2 / target. sudo chroot target. sudo update-grub.

Comment: One more question: Am I overwriting the contents of the 30_uefi-firmware file or just appending/inserting what you wrote to it?

Comment: well essentially, deleting the if/then statement so it looks like mine, overwrite the contents

Comment: Okay I've done that. Is there a way I can verify that sda2 is the install partition? sda9 is my / partition so I'm assuming that's different but I just want to be sure. Please forgive my hesitation I'm just aware that I'm treading on eggshells when dealing with disk issues.

Comment: sda9 is the one you want to mount. and the boot partition if you made it seperate

Comment: I attempted to run the command "sudo mount /dev/sda9 / target" as mentioned. The response is the usage guide. Is there a typo in the command?

Comment: open the concol from the home directory  (right click) -- sudo mount /dev/sda9 target

Comment: Okay, I've made the target file in the home directory, edited the file, executed the mount and chroot commands, and upon attempting to execute update-grub I get:

"sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu: Connection refused
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).